# How open database file *.SQLITEDB in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert

[image]how open file *.sqlitedb in QGIS or ArcGIS? You can file convert? Database structure file*sqlitedb is from DB Browser

[image]

Comment: You may have a try with Add vector layer. Your problem is most probably that you have some sort of SQLite database but it in not SpatiaLite database. Do you know from what software your data are?

Comment: This file *.sqlitedb is from navigation Locus for android.

Comment: Are there any info available about the database structure that Locus is using or a sample database?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [tour]. Please also [edit] your question to include what you've tried, where you've gotten stuck, and the text of any error messages. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for useful info.

Comment: database structure is under the title

Comment: So you seem to have raster tiles stored as blobs into a table and x, y, z and s attributes used for naming the tiles and projection is fixed and probably EPSG:3857 . I guess that QGIS cannot read them out-of-the-box but  it should not be so hard for someone with good Python skills to write a plugin for that.

Comment: projection is WGS84, i dont know more...

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteDB can be the file extension of any SQLite database, which can in turn have map information stored in it in any number of ways.

However, the good news is that in this case, the table structure you posted seems identical with that of a tiled map generated by MOBAC (Mobile Atlas Creator) in RMaps or Galileo (now Guru) maps format. I note from https://mobac.sourceforge.io/faq.html that MOBAC can also be made to read such file formats (with a bit of fancy footwork with configuration files) and convert to a locally stored zipped set of tiles, or even easier an MBTiles format database that you should then be able to import into QGIS without any difficulty.

Of course, it's possible the Locus file format is a bit different, but MOBAC can read several different sqlitedb tile formats, so it's worth a try.

I'm not familiar with Locus since I don't use Android, but it seems its offline maps come from various sources (including OpenStreetMap), and I assume whatever GPS tracks or waypoints you may have added could be exported separately. So you could also explore going back to the source for the underlying basemap, importing that into QGIS directly, and then layering on your tracks/waypoints. But I'm making assumptions about what you're trying to do that may not be warranted.

Comment: Thank you for information. Mobile atlas creator can create file.sqlitedb from maps , not convert or open file.sqlitedb, can you help me?

Comment: @lv38 According to https://mobac.sourceforge.io/MOBAC/README.HTM#FileBased (see the very last sentence at the end of the document, and example linked to there), it _can_ be made to open sqlite in suitable formats. It does need creating/adapting your own xml settings file.